# Send js value to php controller by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this button

```
<button  id="<?php echo $u['id']?>" name="activation" onclick="handleButton(this);" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></button>
```

And this button related to this

```
<td id="<?php echo $u['id']?>"><?php echo $u['id']?></td>
```

I'm using this script to send value of button to my php controller

```
function handleButton(obj) {
    var javascriptVariable = obj.id;
//  alert (javascriptVariable);
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/active_users",
          dataType: 'text',
          data: 'myname='+javascriptVariable,
          success: function (data){
            }

    });
}
```

When I use alert, the result of `javascriptVariable` is correct and I want it in my controller so I'm trying in my controller to do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['activation']))
{
    $name = $this->input->post('myname');
    var_dump($name);
}
```

But I get `null` value, what is the wrong?

Comment: But you are calling the $_POST variable `myname` so there will not be anything called `activation` in the $_POST array

Comment: Better way of passing parameters `data: {myname: javascriptVariable},`

Comment: Is your button inside a form?

Comment: @gre_gor yes it is

Answer (score 4):

When you pass data from the browser via AJAX only the data you pass in the `data:` parameter is sent to the PHP script.

So if you want to test for `activation` in the PHP script you must actually send that parameter

Also see the amendment to the `data:` parameter creation below. Its easier to read and a lot easier to code correctly when passing more than one parameter as you dont have to remember `&`'s and `+` concatenation.

```
function handleButton(obj) {
    obj.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/active_users",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {activation: 1, myname: obj.id},   // add parameter
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Now the PHP will see 2 parameters in the $_POST array `activation` and `myname`

```
if(isset($_POST['activation']))
{
    $name = $_POST['myname'];
    var_dumb($name);
}
```

Or if you are using a framework which I assume you are

```
if(isset($this->input->post('activation')) {
    $name = $this->input->post('myname');
    var_dumb($name);
}
```

EDIT:

Spotted another issue your button has an attribute `type="submit"` this will cause the javascript to run AS WELL AS the form being submitted in the normal way.

Remove the `type="submit"` attribute and to be doubly sure that the form will not be submitted as well as the AJAX add a call to `preventDefault();` as well before the AJAX call

Comment: @ValiS Well not if you look at the timestamp on my first comment under the question

Comment: didn't see that

Comment: I tired your solution but still null

Comment: Then `obj.id` is not getting the data you think it is

Comment: when I used $name = $_POST['myname']; I get an error (Undefined index: myname)

Comment: See my edit. You are submitting the form and the AJAX call

Comment: after applying your edit, I still get null but it is going to my controller without showing the alert success!!

Comment: I'm using your script, the script skip `success: function (data){alert(data);}` how can the script skip this but it takes me to the controller and run it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think the problem is in the controller

Answer (score 1):

Since the php script is conditioned by a second POST variable [`if(isset($_POST['activation']))`], you should post that as well.

```
function handleButton(obj) {
    var javascriptVariable = obj.id;
//  alert (javascriptVariable);
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/active_users",
          dataType: 'text',
          data: 'myname='+javascriptVariable+'&activation=1',// <-- RIGHT HERE
          success: function (data){
              alert(data);
            }

    });
}
```

SIDE NOTE: you could also echo instead of dump the variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['activation']))
{
    echo $this->input->post('myname');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your ajax function :

```
function handleButton(obj) {
    var javascriptVariable = obj.id;
    //alert (javascriptVariable);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/active_users",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {myname: javascriptVariable},
        success: function (data) {}
    });
}
```

And in your PHP script, you can do `$_POST['myname']` to get it (maybe `$this->input->post('myname')` can work, you can test it)

Comment: @MacBooc `DataType` identifies what data will be returned to the javascript not what is being sent by the javascript

Comment: @MacBooc No problem, its probably a useful addition to the OP's knowledge anyway

Answer (score 0):

Look  two `id`

```
<button  id="<?php echo $u['id']?>" name="activation" onclick="handleButton(this);" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"></button>
```

AND

```
<td id="<?php echo $u['id']?>"><?php echo $u['id']?></td>
```

For both html elements `id` is same.It can not be used with in the same page.This may cause a problem for you...

Comment: but the result is correct when I alert javascriptVariable!

Comment: then congrats..but try to work with different `id`.But on case alerting value instead of id name problem may arise.